# "things are bad" - "issues are bad" - "stuff is bad"?

Tags: terminology

I'm a designer and I want to design one tattoo when I want to express something like two parts:
Things are just bad (or doomed) // but // they will get worse.
And I want to represent it with Medusa (wich had lot of heads = lot of problems). But I find the sentence too "basic English learner" because "things" sounds too material, too basic, so I have thought of "issues"  but that reminds me of mental issues, and that's not my idea. So my third option is 'stuff' but stuff is like -for me I think- a bunch of things.
So I don't know what to use, by 'things' I want to express: situations, circunstamces, life in general, and maybe I'm wrong and "things" is the right word in this case. I'm looking for a word more actual, maybe there is some word in the urban slang?

Comment: You could say "things are bad" or something like that. An alternative might be "life is hard/bad/sucks", or "shit is hard" (where shit means things in general).

Comment: What Stuart said above. Also @Cascabel Don't be judgy. The OP is a **tattoo designer** looking for the correct words to describe their design concept.